# C++11: The mutable lambda doesn't seem to change the variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, mutable

I've got a quick test below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int i=2;
    auto f=[=]()mutable{++i;};
    f();
    f();
    cout<<i<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But the result it still prints "2". Why i is not modified inside a mutable lambda? I'm using clang --std=c++1z.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int i=2;
auto f=[=]()mutable{++i;};
f();
f();
std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
```

this prints 2.

```
int i=2;
auto f=[&](){++i;};
f();
f();
std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
```

this prints 4.

```
int i=2;
auto f=[=]()mutable{++i; std::cout << i << std::endl;};
f();
f();
std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
```

this prints 3 4 2.

`=` **copies** captured data into the lambda.

If `mutable` the **copies** can be modified.

`&` **references** captured data in the lambda.

Modifying things through references is legal.

`[=]` is the same as `[i]`, and `[&]` is the same as `[&i]` in this context (you can explicitly list captures, or let them be captured implicitly by listing none and using `=` or `&`).

Answer (score 10):

You use `[=]` for your capture which means the lambda gets a copy of `i`.  This copy is independent from the `i` in `main`.

What you need to do is capture by reference `[&]` in order to apply the changes to the `i` in `main`.

Comment: It might help to illustrate the difference if the lambda printed out it's own copy of `i`. You would then see that it's value is different from `int i` from the scope of `main`.

Answer (score 3):

`[=]` means you're capturing `i` by value. Even the mutable lambda could modify it but it's just a copy inside the lambda, then any modification on it would have nothing to do with the original variable.

You might want [capture-by-reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture), and then `mutable` is not needed again. e.g.

```
auto f = [&i]() {++i;};
```